# GAS: How to allow other people to use your library without sharing the code

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, publish

How can I create a library in google app script in which I can share just the library key and people can use it, without sharing the code properly? I am trying hard to find a solution, but I failed.

I don't want to share the library for the world. I just want to use the library in different google drives, without having to share the code, but just the library/project key.

I found this link on stackoverflow that the guy had basically the same question as me, but it didn't has a good answer: [How to share Spreadsheet with reference to a custom (private) library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22183246/how-to-share-spreadsheet-with-reference-to-a-custom-private-library)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

it is currently imposible with you requirement to end up "sharing a library key."

you must give at least read access to the library file for this case of running the script functions directly from the spreadsheet.

Once a script uses the library, and the user has view permission on the container script, a curious user could use the apps script debugger to "step into" a library function and there it is, the library source code.

If you were to instead publish the script as a web app, you could hide the library but that option does not apply in your case as you are making copies of the spreadsheet, and services do not get copied, need to be re-published.

Another option, but which does not give the library key in your requirement, is to publish an apps script service that uses the library and implements an API, which the other scripts (inside each spreadsheet copy) use. This however will not scale as quotas will be deducted from the API service publisher, and not the users that call the API.